# Looking for a way to derive the velocity distribution along x axis given the distribution for a general velocity

Tags: kinetic-theory, boltzmann-equation

Without recourse to statistical mechanics my book derives the well known Maxwell Boltzmann velocity distribution which is:
$$dN(v)=N\left(\frac{m}{2 \pi k T}\right)^{3 / 2} e^{-m v^{2} / 2 k T} 4 \pi v^{2} d v, $$ but then it simply gives me the formula for the distribution along $x$-axis without proof as$$
d N\left(v_{x}\right)=N\left(\frac{m}{2 \pi k T}\right)^{1 / 2} e^{-m v_{x}^{2} / 2 k T} d v_{x}.$$
I've tried to derive it myself but I can't make any progress.
I'll be grateful if someone would just point out how to proceed but it should be without statistical mechanics because I've not studied it yet.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) the velocity is equally divided among the three directions $x$, $y$, and$z$. So the $\frac 1 2$ in the exponential for the distribution in the $x$ direction, becomes three times the $\frac 1 2$ in the expression for the total velocity i.e. $\frac 3 2$ (or the factor $\frac 3 2$ becomes $\frac 1 2$).

Comment: What about the$4\pi v^ 2$

Comment: The factor $4\pi v^2$ is the surface of a circle with radius $v$. in 3d $v$-space. In which you make the integration of the first expression. This disappears in the 1d case of the second equation.